# Групповой чат на Yii2?

Tags: yii2

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли готовый модуль чата с возможностью диалога, а так же группового чата для Yii2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вот прям первый пункт в выдаче поиска. https://packagist.org/packages/bubasuma/yii2-simplechat
Полистайте, выберите, что нравится: https://packagist.org/?q=yii2%20chat&p=0
А так, чат же совсем несложно сделать, тем более на yii2, где уже есть расширения для работы с вебсокетом и всякие снипеты бутстраповские готовые.

Comment: вот первый пункт как раз без групповой возможности)